# How to extend sequelize class methods?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Is it possible to extend my sequelize model to have methods other than `findAll` or `findOne`.

I want to have something like:

```js
class Transaction extends Model {
  
  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.StripePayment, {
      foreignKey: 'stripePaymentId',
      as: 'stripePayment',
    });
  }
    
  async failedTransactions({
    billId
  }) {
    return this.findAll({
      where: {
        billId
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: StripePayment,
          required: false,
        },
      ],
    });
  },
  
  // ...
}
```

Where I can then call

```js
const failedTransactions = await Transaction.failedTransaction({ billId }) // currently throws Transaction.failedTransaction is not a function
```

Is seems to recognise it as a function if I define the method as static inside the model

```js
static async failedTransactions({
    billId
  }) {
    ...
  }
```

However, the associations don't seem to work inside a static method. I am guessing this is because the method gets defined before my model links it's associations.*

- associations work when I call the `findAll` query in my controller (i.e. not in the model)

Comment: _However, the associations don't seem to work inside a static method._ – what is the exact error you get in that case? Defining `failedTransaction` as static would be the way to go.

Comment: The error is `TypeError: include.model.getTableName is not a function` which I believe happens when the associations are defined correctly. But I am confident they are defined since the query works in the controller level of my code

Comment: I am not sure how to fix this class method error but `scope` sounds like a good alternative for this.  https://sequelize.org/master/manual/scopes.html